# How can i detect which board i am using through the i2c of the raspberry pi

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-models, revision

I am working on a project where i moved from raspberry pi model B to B+.

So i need to change my audio driver to work on both models by doing some GPIO

changes .

The requirement is, i have to find the board using the i2c.

I dont know how to do that.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know which revision the rpi board belongs to using c language program](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23762/how-to-know-which-revision-the-rpi-board-belongs-to-using-c-language-program)

Comment: Yaa, i searched but i didnt understand anything. @ Milliways

Comment: I dont know how both questions are same. This is using i2c and the other question is using how to read a revision number. Can u explain clearly, how both are same

Comment: What do you mean by "find the board"?  What do you mean by "using the I2C"?

Comment: I dont know much about I2C, i thought that i have to use some I2C function or any I2C api for getting the board revision. finding the board revision by reading the "/proc/cpuinfo" file is not I2C, i think.

Comment: @vvn No, I2C is purely a communications protocol.  It has no knowledge of the underlying hardware and no mechanism to talk to anything but devices on the same bus.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the command:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

This will show you a 'map' of adresses to your connected i2c devices.